# Mongoose TTL not working on Timestamps

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have issue getting mongoose timestamps work with mongoose expires. I see no MongoDB TTL Index on updatedAt.

schema:

```
const AdminSessionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  UID: String,
  device: String,
  updatedAt : { type: Date, expires: 60 }
}, { collection: 'admin.session', timestamps: true });
```

mongoshell:

```
> db.admin.session.getIndexes()                   
[                                                 
        {                                         
                "v" : 1,                          
                "key" : {                         
                        "_id" : 1                 
                },                                
                "name" : "_id_",                  
                "ns" : "development.admin.session"
        }                                         
]
```

Is this the right way to make it work? or am I missing something.

Comment: Have you created indexes using db.collection.createIndex?
You should create an index to a field to make TTL work..

Comment: @Jocket mongoose expire worked without db.collection.createIndex previously with out timestamps: true as mongoose created Index for me.

Comment: Have you checked using ensureIndex..